# How to get text from a QLineEdit dynamically?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, qlineedit

How could get `String(Text)` from `QlineEdit`?
I tried Like this.
`myArea.getList()` function is get string value and check database with string value and return List

```
self.a = QLineEdit()
self.b = QlineEdit()
....

self.b = self.myArea.getList(str(self.a.textChanged.connect(self.textchanged)))

def textchanged(self, text):
    self.my_edit = text
```

Input text in `a`, then `a` changes. read `a`, check data by `a`, `b`'s data created, Input text in `b`, read `b`, check data by `b`

First, I don't know how to get `QLineEdit()`'s value. 
print `QLineEdit` Text works but return String.

Comment: I don´t understand.What is "my_edit" and "myArea"?You only need return the value in textchanged function. `def textchanged(self, text):return text`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a complete example how to get the value from `self.a` and `self.b` and set the values to each other. Maybe this [tutorial](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/widgets2/) helps you, too.

You can not use the return value of the methods `self.textchangedA` or `self.textchangedB`, so you have to make use of the member variables of the class.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import logging
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class MyWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.setLayout(vbox)

        self.a = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.b = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)

        vbox.addWidget(self.a)
        vbox.addWidget(self.b)

        self.a.textChanged.connect(self.textchangedA)
        self.b.textChanged.connect(self.textchangedB)

    def textchangedA(self, text):
        log.info("Text from a: %s", text)
        log.info("Text from b: %s", self.b.text())
        # do the processing

    def textchangedB(self, text):
        log.info("Text from b: %s", text)
        log.info("Text from a: %s", self.a.text())



def test():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWidget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    test()
```

Comment: Thanks.. But How could I use return value?? It used just only print 'values' not getting 'values'.. So I mean when I add new self.aReturn = self.textcahngedA -> print self.aReturn -> print out None    / If I self.aRetunr = self.a.textChanged.connect(self.textchangedA)  -> just bound method memory address priting out

Comment: I really Super Thank you ! But.. I don't know how to get the self.a's string value independently out of the textchangedA method... I mean extract the QLineEdit's string value and use this value as independent value in the class. Not just print out

Comment: with `self.a.text()` you get the string value and with `self.b.text()` you get the string value of b. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Oh, I implement method in method!! I solve the problem!! I Really Thank for you!! Really!! THANK YOU!!

Comment: You are welcome. If you could upvote or/and accept helpful answers other people can see what helped you most and the answerer gets some points as reward ;)